# TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when wrapping some already working pygame code into a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to make code that checks if the letter the user pressed was the first letter of any word in a list of strings using pygame, the list is generated by urrlib importing from a web page then I have code as follows to check
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if x[str(event.key)] in [i[0] for i in final]:
                return('Forward')
            else:
                return 'nope', final
```

but when I run the code it only prints 'nope' and an empty list, I tried wrapping it in a function and calling it afterwards but I got the error
    TypeError: 'Function' object has no attribute getitem

Note: final is the list of words and x is a dict referring to the value of each letter since event.key returns an int id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.key`s are just integers and if you convert them into strings, you only get strings like `'97'` or `'115'`.

You should use the `event.unicode` attribute if you need the actual letter. Then you can use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function and pass this generator expression, `any(word.lower().startswith(event.unicode) for word in strings)` to see if a word starts with the entered letter.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
strings = ['some', 'Random', 'words']

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            print(event.unicode)
            if any(word.lower().startswith(event.unicode) for word in strings):
                print('Forward')
            else:
                print('nope')

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```